# QT Layout - initial directions

Tags: qt

I am new to QT. I'm trying to understand the layout mechanism by trying to implement this small window seen below. It has the following elements under the QWidget that's the main window:

1. One big QWidget that stretches on all the client area.
2. Two QWidget containers on the top of the window. Both should have the same height, but the right one stretches horizontally, as the window grows/shrinks.
3. one button container widget on the top right, with fixed height and width
4. Large QWidget container filling the rest of the client area, that should resize as the window resizes.

The parent window itself is resizeable.

I'm looking for hints as to what layout I should use. How do I achieve this programatically? define what stretches automatically, what stays with a fix size? and how the proportions are kept where they need to be kept.

I'd appreciate any pointer you may have.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest, and IMHO best, way to accomplish this is via the QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayouts.  You can do this via the designer in QtCreator, but I find it doesn't work perfectly if you need to adapt things over time.  If it's a static set of widgets, I do suggest designing it using the QtCreator designer as it'll greatly simplify your life.

If you're going to do it programatically, the main window should be set to use a QVBoxLayout and then two sub-QVBoxLayout's after that, where the bottom one is configured to take any space it can get.  Then in the top QVBoxLayout, add a QHBoxLayout with your two upper components.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand that a single item in a layout object will automatically occupy the entire size of that layout. how do you set the area utilization ratio with two items? say if you want one to be fixed and the other stretchable, or one 40% and the other 60%. I can't find the "keywords" to use for this. not from an API standpoint, or even in the QT-Desitner GUI.

Comment: This is the best resource for understanding that particular question.  It explains lots of things, including "sizePolicy" (stretching by weight).  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html

Answer (score 3):

to set a widget to fixed size in code you call setFixedSize( int h, int w ) on the widget. To do it in Designer click on the widget and look in the property editor in the QWidget section. open the sizePolicy thingy and set horizontal and/or vertical to fixed. Then open Geometry and set the width and Height.

To make them stretch at different ratios in code you use a separate argument when using a box layout. eg layout->addWidget( button1, 1 ); layout->addWidget (button2, 2); this would cause button2 to expand at twice the rate of button1. To do this in designer, open the sizePolicy property of the widgets and set the HorizontalStrech and/or VerticalSretch. Note that the size policy needs to not be Fixed in this case for the direction you want to set the stretch on. Also it will never let a widget shrink below its minimum size (it would rather mess up the ratio than shrink something too small).